# on what error log settings can I find app error logs that google clould compute engine apps throw

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've deployed an app using googles cloud compute engine service.

I get an error when I try to register a new user:

`We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.`

I'm in the logs section of the google cloud console and it has all sorts of random logs I can look at but I cant find where the errors that the app coding itself caused caused are put, e.g. I'm sure its a mail configuration problem that is causing the error message for new registered users but I cant fix the problem until I find out what the actual error is.

Where exactly are actual app errors put, because they aren't displayed on the page the like in production on my local computer. (I'm using a rails app if that makes a difference to anything)

Answer (score 0):

All errors are logged in the logging section, try applying filters or sorting the logs by date. Sometimes they take a little while to appear.

Comment: ruby has gone beta and I doubt this is a platform bug, maybe worth putting a big ass try block and log a handled exception, to be honest if there is absolutely no logs being genertaed then maybe the platform is not initialising correctly, does your rails app run locally without any error ?

Comment: Yes it runs locally without any errors. problem is that im not sure the smtp settings are setup correctly or if its even that. I cant tell unless I see an error message. I guess Ill keep looking through the filters.